# Prove inequalities of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

> Prove:
>
> If generalized Cantor hypothesis holds, then for all sets $X$ and $Y$,  from
>
> $\vert X\vert < \vert Y \vert$ follows $\vert \mathcal{P}(X)\vert < \vert \mathcal{P}(Y) \vert$.
>
> Generalized Cantor hypothesis:
>
> There do **not** exist such infinite sets $A$ and $B$, for which would hold $\vert A \vert <\vert B \vert < \vert \mathcal{P}(A) \vert.$

I am not sure what exactly I should do here, because it look like it obviously follows from Cantor's theorem, but that is probably not right.

Comment: It is obvious, if $|X|<|Y|$ but $|P(X)|=|P(Y)|$, then $|X|<|Y|<|P(X)|$

Comment: Thanks, I just tought it’s strange because, it was an exam question and I thought it would be more complicated.